# Understanding gcloud's persistant disk in order to sustain file write throughput

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am trying to understand gcloud's local SSD performance.

I want to understand what specs of local SSD I would need in order to store 1000 files that are 1/10 of a megabytes in size (100k) per second.

[image]

Also, what is the difference between **"Write throughput per GB"** and **"Write throughput per instance"**?

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of the performance quotas are [in the documentation you cited](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/performance):

> disk IOPS and throughput performance increases linearly with the size
>   of the disk until it reaches the following per-instance limits

So,  increasing reads/writes and throughput, per GB of disk size, up to a limit for one VM instance. Adding resiliency has a performance cost, as does cheaper spindle based options.

You have not provided the other inputs for choosing storage, the required capacity and durability. Ingesting 1,000 files per second is nice, but how long will it do that? How long are the files retained? Remember that [local SSDs are wiped when stopped](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/#localssds). Use these decisions to do your own calculations, such as a capacity planning spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

My background is enterprise storage systems, so I will help you with some basics.

Write throughput per GB means per disk. Write throughput per instance means the total of all disks attached to the instance.

**Analysis 1:**

Your goal is to store 1,000 files of 100 KB each per second. Ignoring the difference between KB and KiB, this is 100 MB per second. High, but not unreasonable with today's storage. Now factor in the file system metadata overhead, latency, etc. and round this number up by 25%. This means you need sustained write performance of 125 MB /sec.

From your chart, selecting the fastest persistent (non-local) disk for this example: Zonal SSD.

This disk provides 0.48 MB per second of write performance per GB. You need 125 MB / sec. Therefore you need at least 260 GB of storage (125 / 0.48). This is not a big drive. I would select 1 TB to provide some room. However, make note of the maximum write performance range (76-400 MB/sec).

**Analysis 2:**

Disk IOPS. If you take 125 MB and, for this example, assume that a single I/O is 4 KB, then you need at least 32K IOPS. Using the same Zonal SSD you need at least 1,092 GB of storage (125 MB / 4K). Note that 32K IOPS exceeds maximum supported write performance.

Notes:

Google performance numbers have specifics:

1. I/O Block Size is 8 KB or smaller for IOPS performance numbers.
2. I/O Block Size is 256 KB or larger for write performance (MB/sec).

Do not use my calculated numbers for your use case. Review what I have written so that you have an understanding at a very simple level on how to figure out performance numbers for storage. I am not factoring in network bandwidth, latencies, required CPU performance and many other factors. When I design systems, I use math similar to the above and then I benchark with real world example cases. I try to find the maximum sustained rates and try to model what our enterprise applications actually do.

One final note. These types of IOPS in the cloud world are expensive (a relative term). I will leave it to you to estimate storage costs.

Comment: One important thing I didn't emphasis is that I can use local disks, and if the instance goes down the data can go with it.  Any data that I will need will be stored in a db after I filter that raw data.  Should I use the calculators to get an idea on pricing?

Comment: Google has good pricing calculators. I have explained some basics to help get you started. There is a lot more to consider when selecting your storage subsystems.